# Display a consistent Google Plus icon on ALL pages of my site

Tags: plugins, javascript, scripts, google-plus

My website is http://tablified.com and I have managed to setup the Google Plus script. The issue is that every page of the site displays a different Google Plus count. For example, if you go on my site you will see that I have about 180 Google Pluses. Now, if you click on something like "Tablified Apps" you will see that the Google Plus number on the top left corner of the screen is changed to 21. How do I display the Google Plus account for the main page across the entire website regardless of the page being displayed? Where should I place the script exactly? I am running this site on Wordpress. Perhaps a plugin could fix this and save me the hassle? The issue is that I need to have it at that EXACT location and I feel like a plugin would not accomplish this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly [set the target url](http://code.google.com/apis/+1button/#target-url) or it will use the rel canonical (if present) or grab URL of the current page via js.

[Use the button generator](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/) and click advanced options to set the target URL, or:

```
<g:plusone href="http://tablified.com/"></g:plusone>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the target URL, you need to be aware of that your visitors will only be able to Google +1 one time and that's for the home page. If a user likes another section or page of your site like the Tablified Games they won't be able to Google +1 that page because they have already done that because it's always the same Google +1.

And you have more than the 180 Google +1. The 180 are just for the homepage and the others you see are for the specific pages.

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet

```
<!-- Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>

<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
<g:plusone></g:plusone>
```